# Pass Parameters to SQL Triggers via asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, triggers

I have an Employee table in my database. values are inserted into this table through an asp.net page. I want to make a trigger on Employee insert which will allow the insertion only if it is made by the user having "id=1110", all other users insertion must be rejected. I do not know how to pass userid as a parameter to trigger. Anyone can please help me???

Comment: when is id 1110 coming from?

Comment: U need to add that condition in ur trigger.

Comment: 1110 is the id coming from Admin page....Admin login to his page and he can register a new employee...I want to check if Admin '1110' has performed registration or not.!

Comment: #Paresh J can you tell me how?

Comment: You cannot pass parameters into a trigger - the trigger operates **solely** on the database table it's attached to, and its rows

Comment: Admins having different id's can login Admin page, but they can not register an employee...this is what i want to implement.

Comment: You can get values of row inserted in "Employee" table from "inserted" table in trigger, using that you can check "id" column.

Comment: #Paresh J in Employee table there is no column which tells that this employee is registered by Admin having id '1110'. Employee table have only one id column which is the id of registered employee.!

Comment: Do you need to solve this on database level or can you also check this constraint through application permissions? It is much easier to solve this on application level, e.g. by introducing a new permission `AddEmployee` that only is only granted to this administrator. Otherwise, you need to change the database code whenever another administrator should perform this task. When administrator 1110 is on vacation, it will be your task to change the database if an employee is to be added; in contrast, there might be a UI for application permissions that someone else can use to assign the right.

Comment: @HamidRaza: Then it's database design constraint. You need to add this coz without it it would be difficult for u to know who hv added the record.

Comment: Yep...#Markus..I am gonna check this constraint through application permissions...
Thanks everyone.....

Comment: Two methods of passing a small amount of additional information to a trigger is context_info https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180125.aspx. Also the client can set something on the connection that will show up in the host_name function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triggers cannot pass parameters - you have to operate within the database operation. Therefore, unless the Employee table has a CreateBy or LastUpdateBy referencing the id of the user making the change, you would need to wrap the INSERT into a stored procedure that would perform that check before performing the INSERT.

If by chance your Employee table has a CreateBy that contains the id of the user performing the change, then a trigger such as this below should work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_Employees_RegisterAdminOnly ON dbo.Employees
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED WHERE CreateBy <> 1110) BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Unauthorized registration', 16, 1)
        ROLLBACK
        RETURN
    END
END
GO
```

Comment: Thanks Jason....I am gonna wrap the insert in stored procedure..:-)

Answer (score 0):

you may call the stored procedure below in your c# code after creating the trigger:

```
--table|start
CREATE TABLE dbo.z_Employee (ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1), Name VARCHAR(100), UserModify SMALLINT)
--table|end



--stored procedure for inserting new employee|start
CREATE PROC dbo.z_AddEmployee(@Name VARCHAR(100), @UserModify SMALLINT)
AS
--for debugging|start
--DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(100)
--  , @UserModify SMALLINT = 1112
--for debugging|end
INSERT dbo.z_Employee (Name, UserModify)
VALUES (@Name, @UserModify)

--for debugging|start
--SELECT e.*
--FROM dbo.z_Employee e WITH(NOLOCK)
--for debugging|end
--stored procedure for inserting new employee|end



--trigger for disallowing inserts|start
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.z_DoNotAllowOtherUser
ON dbo.z_Employee
FOR INSERT
AS

IF EXISTS
    (SELECT TOP 1 i.ID
    FROM INSERTED i
    WHERE i.UserModify <> 1110)
BEGIN
    DELETE e
    FROM dbo.z_Employee e WITH(NOLOCK)
        JOIN INSERTED i ON i.ID = e.ID
END
--trigger for disallowing inserts|end
```